# How can I draw to the display, without OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I've been learning OpenGL, and as I sit trying to write my VBOs, PBOs, VAOs, textures, quads, bindings, fragment shaders, vertex shaders, and a whole suite of other modern abstractions upon abstractions built after decades of evolution, I wonder: Isn't the display nothing but a large block of memory?

I've heard of tales, that in the "good ol' days" (such as the Commodore 64), all you had to do was assign a value to an arbitrary byte in memory, and the screen would change a pixel. Extremely simple and elegant. In the modern day, this has changed with layers upon layers of abstractions and safeguards, such that changing a pixel on your display is several hundred feet away.

This begs the question, is it possible in the modern day to just "update a pixel of the screen"? Is it possible to write my own graphics driver or something, where I can send commands to some C wrapper which interfaces with the GPU to change those pixels? This is an extremely broad question, but I'm curious. The answer I'm looking for to this question would provide a rough outline of what you'd have to do in order to be able to arbitrarily get some C code to set a pixel on the screen, as well as a rough outline of why OpenGL has progressed the way it has - what problems did VBOs, PBOs, VAOs, bindings, shaders, etc. solve, and how we got to where we are today.

Comment: This is highly dependent on your hardware and OS. I think it's still possible to emulate mode X on your PC, (old games still work.)

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't the display nothing but a large block of memory?

Yes, it is called a framebuffer.

> I've heard of tales, that in the "good ol' days" (such as the Commodore 64)

Your current PC works like that right when you power it up! If you use the CPU to write into video memory, that is called a software renderer.

> In the modern day, this has changed with layers upon layers of abstractions and safeguards, such that changing a pixel on your display is several hundred feet away.

No, they are not abstractions/safeguards for "changing pixels". Nowadays software renderers are not used anymore. Instead, you have to tell the GPU (which is another computer on its own) how to draw. That "talk" is what the APIs (like OpenGL) do for you.

Now, the GPUs are meant to be fast at drawing, and that requires specialized code and data structures. Those are all the things you mention: VBOs, PBOs, VAOs, shaders, etc. (in OpenGL parlance). There is no way around that, because GPUs are different hardware.

> is it possible in the modern day to just "update a pixel of the screen"?

Yes, but that will end up being drawn somehow by the GPU, even if it looks to you like a memory write.

> Is it possible to write my own graphics driver or something, where I can send commands to some C wrapper which interfaces with the GPU to change those pixels?

Yes, but that "C wrapper" is the graphics driver. A graphics driver for a modern GPU is very complex.

> what you'd have to do in order to be able to arbitrarily get some C code to set a pixel on the screen

You cannot write a "C program" to write to a graphical screen because the C standard does not concern itself with graphical displays.

So it depends on your operating system, your hardware, whether you want 2D or 3D acceleration support, the API you choose...

> as well as a rough outline of why OpenGL has progressed the way it has - what problems did VBOs, PBOs, VAOs, bindings, shaders, etc. solve, and how we got to where we are today.

See above.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own frame buffer - that is just an integer array - and do rasterization on it, then use for example the Windows GDI function `SetBitmapBits()` to draw it to the display in one go. The final draw-to-display command depends on the operating system.

How you do the rasterization on your framebuffer is completely up to you. You can use the CPU to draw individual pixels or rasterize lines and triangles, see for example this demo of my old CPU graphics engine using Windows GDI: https://youtu.be/GFzisvhtRS4.
Using the CPU is fine as long as you do not rasterize large datasets. From my experience, the limit to real-time 60fps rendering on the CPU is ~50k lines per frame.

If you want to rasterize really large datasets, you have to use a GPU in some way. Since the framebuffer is just an integer array, you can transfer it to/from the GPU using OpenCL or CUDA and on the GPU - if your dataset happens to already be in video memory - do all the rasterization extremely fast in parallel. For this you will need an additional z-buffer to decide which pixels to overdraw by occluding geometries. This way you can rasterize approximately 30 Million lines per frame at 60fps. This demo is rendered on the GPU in real time using OpenCL: https://youtu.be/lDsz2maaZEo

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in the modern day to just "update a pixel of the screen"?

Yes. In Windows for example, you can use [`SetPixel()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setpixel) to draw a pixel or [`BitBlt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt) to draw in bulk. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005744/how-to-display-pixels-on-screen-directly-from-a-raw-array-of-rgb-values-faster-t) Q/A

This works fine, but this means you're using the CPU for rendering and you'll find the GPU is much more effective for this task, especially if you require decent framerate and non-trivial graphics. The reason there's these "whole suite of other modern abstractions upon abstractions" is to serve as an interface to the GPU since it has an independent set of memory and totally different execution model. Other GPU libraries (OpenCL, DirectX, Vulkan, etc) all have the same kind of abstractions.

---

I've glossed over many nuances but I hope the point gets across.